# mysql How to delete all data except some data

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I use mysql, nestjs, typeorm.

When I delete `user` table, I want to delete all but not some table data.

If a `user` withdraws from my service, I want to delete everything except the information in the `cat` table.

```sql
User [id, name, age ...]
Cat [id, name, age, userId ...]
Doctor [id, name, address, userId ...]
... [id, ...]
... [id, ...]
```

Is there a way to delete data in all tables except the data in `cat` table?

I am now running a delete query for each table.

```
DELETE FROM Doctor where userId = ${userId}
DELETE FROM ... where userId = ${userId}
DELETE FROM ... where userId = ${userId}
```

However, I write the question because problems can arise when tables are added or deleted.

Please tell me a good way.

Comment: ?? you say you have 2 tables (user,cat) in one part of the question but then imply something else in the last 2 sentences - please clarify your db structure and why 'problems can arise when tables are added or deleted.' And don't assume we are all familiar with typeorm

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry. I've only created a few tables.
I added more data. What I'm worried about is that the data in the table is being deleted one by one, so if I don't delete a table that is added later, or an error may occur because of the deleted table.

Comment: I think you may be looking for referential integrity , in your example I see doctor has a user_id so to prevent deletion of the related user you should place a foreign key on user_id in doctor. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: umm.. If I delete user id=1, I want to delete data with userId=1 from other tables including the doctor table, except for the cat table.

Comment: Read the link, especially the portion dealing with on delete cascade. Alternatively a trigger may be appropriate.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html - but a trigger cannot know if tables with dependencies on users have been added or deleted and therefore need to be maintained.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you I'll read the link and try to use the trigger.

Comment: If you want to delete all data for a user, you must keep the row in the user table in order to keep the row in the cat table (for referential integrity and in order to know which user is referenced in the cat table). What I would probably do is establish a process where the user to be deleted gets copied into a history table (user_hist, cat_hist, or just one table with the joined data). Then you can just delete the user from the original users table and have your DBMS do this cascadingly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner oh! It seems to be the best way. thank you!

Comment: Provide your tables structures as complete CREATE TABLE scripts, not as a list of columns. *now running a delete query for each table.* MySQL supports multiple-table DELETE. *I want to delete all but not some table data.* If FK is present and ON DELETE is specified correctly then all subdata should be deleted automatically for ON DELETE CASCADE and stored for ON DELETE SET NULL while deleting main row. If not then you need in 2 separate queries - first breaks the relation and second deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you need to make some value to be null in column 2 when you delete user as example you can use **onDelete : *"SET NULL"***

in cat Entity you can use

```js
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user,
        {
            onDelete: 'SET NULL'
        })
    @JoinColumn()
    public createdBy: UserEntity;
```